# Tridecane isomer name

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the name of this $\ce{C13H28}$ isomer:

$\hspace{5.5cm}$[image: molecule]

I think it must be "4-ethyl-6,7-methylnonane," but I saw somewhere that its name is "6-ethyl-3,4-methylnonane". Why? The ethyl number must be smaller, isn't it? (because E is before M). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alphabetic order dictates which *order* the substituents are *written* in, but not the numbering of their positions.  Numbering is determined by what minimizes the numbers.  E.g. 3-ethyl-2-methylhexane is correct, but 4-ethyl-5-methylhexane is not.